# C# selenium Upload Pop up is not opening while running script

Tags: c#, selenium, upload

Steps to reproduce:

1. Trying to click on the upload button while running script through c# selenium.
2. File upload popup window is not getting displayed.

Can anyone suggest me know whether we have to give some permission or settings to visual studio for allowing interaction with window popups.?

Note:it's happening while the script is running but working fine when trying manually.

Comment: Can you upload some html sample for upload event?

Comment: h2>Resume Upload Form</h2>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="Submitted" value="true">
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td>First Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Last Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="LastName" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Resume</td>
 <td><input type="file" name="Resume"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>